# Starting Tomcat 6 on Plesk 11.5 Linux

Tags: tomcat

I've been searching without luck for a way to get tomcat running on my server. It a linux server with Plesk 11.5 and tomcat 6. I've followed many instructions but this one has pictures that are current: [guide](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Plesk/how-do-i-setup-tomcat-within-plesk-3992/). I get to about step 4 but the start button is grayed out.

I am trying to upload and run a java application from a .WAR file, but this is the first step. Please advise, thanks!

Comment: One of the best things to do in this situation is to remove plesk, and use the command line.  That way, you gain actual linux experience and avoid the many drawbacks of plesk.

Comment: @FalconMomot I am using Plesk to host websites and make things easier for me and my clients. Why would I remove Plesk? Given your logic, I should just learn to code in C and script every action in Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Tomcat is not installed on your server, or your license key does not support Tomcat.

Check the license page inside Plesk to make sure you're allowed to use it (requires the Power Pack license upgrade).

Comment: So far this seems like my issue. I checked the license page and sure enough, tomcat is "off"